# Google PageSpeed Insights warning for "Leverage Browser Caching". How can I cache these files in htaccess better?

Tags: .htaccess, caching, browser-cache, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I put the following code in my htaccess to improve browser caching and page speed. But Google PageSpeed Insights is still giving me a red flag saying I should "leverage browser caching" on many objects even though they are already cached to a set duration.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c> 
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 30 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 30 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 259200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 259200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 259200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 259200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 259200  seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 259200 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 259200 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

(259200 seconds = 3 days)

And here is what Google PageSpeed Insights is saying I need to do better at "leverage browser caching". Though as you can see all of the files and images are set to a duration.

```
http://m.addthisedge.com/…-55fe4c5f093b7938/_ate.track.config_resp (60 seconds)
http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js (10 minutes)
http://website.com/externalimage.jpg (2 hours)
http://website.com/externalimage2.jpg (2 hours)
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js (2 hours)
http://example.com/img/menu.png (3 days)
http://example.com/img/nextpage.png (3 days)
http://example.com/img/search.png (3 days)
http://example.com/img/signup.jpg (3 days)
http://example.com/img/signup.png (3 days)
http://example.com/logo.png (3 days)
http://example.com/style.css (3 days)
http://example.com/css.css (3 days)
```

Is Google trying to say that 2 hours for some of these images, and 3 days for some of the other files not long enough? What I can do to improve the performance for this? And is it really giving me a red flag for its own google analytics.js file? Is there a way that I can cache the external addthis and analytics files better? And I assume that I wouldn't actually want to cache the analytics file cause that could conflict with the tracking of users maybe?

And is there a way that I can change the caching of the images that are on the external domain, that are currently set to 2 hours? I'd like to cache them for a much longer duration.

Any help to increase my page performance with this is greatly appreciated. I don't know why it's red flagging me for these files that are already set to cache. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, I discovered that Google recommends at least 7 days of caching and will send warnings for only 3 days.

I also learned that there's no way to increase the cache time on remote files as I do not control those servers.

I set the caching of my own files to at least 7 days just to appease Pagespeed Insights.